# URL Rewrite Regex Match No Hash and Empty

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write some regex to match some URLs for our url rewriting...

I'm basically trying to match ANY url that does NOT contain a # in it AND is NOT empty or just a preceding /.

So for example:

Matched: /test-url

Matched: /abc123

Not Matched: /#/test-url

Not Matched: /

Not Matched: (nothing)

This is the Regex I've been trying but it's not working.

`^/(?!#.*)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because you are missing the escape `\` character for the `/` and the matching after the negative look a head like `.*` like: `^\/(?!#.*).*`

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lJ9uN2/1)

Based on your comment to match more than one character try this instead: `^\/(?!#.*).+` using `+` instead of `*` at the end of the expression.

[**Online Demo 2**](http://regex101.com/r/lJ9uN2/2)

Comment: This is real close also but its also matching "/" alone

Comment: change last `*` for + like `^\/(?!#.*).+`

Answer (score 1):

Try the below  regex to match the strings that starts with `/` followed by any character not of `#` one or more times.

```
^\/[^#\n]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/3)

OR

```
^\/[^#]+(?=\n)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aO5dB0/2)

Comment: this is good - so close, but it matches "/" only - is there anyway to avoid that, like match /abc123 - basically matching no / alone?

Comment: it matches `/` and it must be followed by one or more non # chars.